# How do I update an element's class on the mouse events for another element?

Tags: javascript

So I've been reading Mozilla's js docs all day, trying to figure this out. I'm still a newb with JavaScript, and I plan on learning this stuff, but I'm getting really frustrated that I can't figure it out and move on to the rest of my project.

[This codepen](http://codepen.io/Bearses/pen/QbPGMP) is what I have so far. I'm trying to change the class for #bear to reflect the mouseOver and MouseOut events for every .thing class. The class should be: past event, then a dash, then current event.

Hopefully the comments illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm sure that I'm doing just about everything wrong here, but don't really know how to proceed with fixing it.

Could anyone help me?

JAVASCRIPT BELOW FOR REFERENCE

```
var thing = "nothing";
document.getElementsByClassName("thing").onMouseOver = function() {
    document.getElementById("bear").className = thing + "-thing" + this.attr("data-thing");
    thing = "thing" + this.attr("data-thing");
}
document.getElementsByClassName("thing").onMouseOut = function() {
    document.getElementById("bear").className = thing + "-nothing";
    thing = "nothing";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection - so you have to iterate over the collection and create your bindings:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("thing");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].onmouseover = function() {
        //replace #bear's class to reflect mouse history
        document.getElementById("bear").className = thing + "-thing" + this.getAttribute("data-thing");
        //update var thing
        thing = "thing" + this.getAttribute("data-thing");
    }

    elems[i].onmouseout = function() {
        //replace #bear's class to reflect mouseOut 
        document.getElementById("bear").className = thing + "-nothing";
       //update var thing to reflect mouseOut
       thing = "nothing";
   }
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNrVEy'

Also, `.attr` is a jQuery method - you need to use `getAttribute` for vanilla JS

Comment: Ack, this is awesome! Thank you so much. I actually see what you're doing here. I guess I've got a lot more reading to do. My next question is, how do I get the variable, "thing" to behave? Example, when I move from Thing1 to Thing2, the header should read "Bear: thing1-thing2"

Answer (score 0):

first things first:  document.getElementsByClaassName(class) returns an ARRAY.  so you can't just do a dot-attribute assignment with it.

Instead:

```
var thing = "nothing";
var thingies = document.getElementsByClassName("thing");
for (i=0;i<thingies.length;i++){
    thingies[i].onMouseOver = function() {
        document.getElementById("bear").className = thing + "-thing" + this.attr("data-thing");
        thing = "thing" + this.attr("data-thing");
    };
    thingies[i].onMouseOut = function() {
        document.getElementById("bear").className = thing + "-nothing";
        thing = "nothing";
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to use jQuery, here is another approach:

```
var thing = "nothing";
$(".thing").hover(function(){

    var newclass=thing + "-thing" + $(this).attr("data-thing");
    $("#bear").addClass(newclass);
    thing = "thing" + $(this).attr("data-thing");
}, function(){
     $("#bear").addClass(thing + "-nothing");
     thing = "nothing";

})
```